# How to disable popup dialog when editing a cell

Tags: slickgrid

How do I disable the popup window that appears when I edit a cell. I copied the simple editing example to my site, and for some reason it always open a small dialog when I edit a cell. I copied this exact code:
http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html

On this example(on the "6pac.github.io" site) if I double click a "Title" cell, it will edit it inline(no popup dialog). On my server, with exactly the same code, it always opens a small dialog when I edit the "Title" cell.
[image]

I tried other editors, like "Integer" and the same thing happens. Is it different versions of libraries?

I am using SlickGrid with a WordPress plugin, with php 7.2, jQuery 3.6.0 and jQuery Migrate 3.3.2. I have the latest version of SlickGrid.

Comment: either you're missing a css file (like `example.css`) or it's simply wordpress that is overriding and applying its own styling over your input. There isn't enough in your question to help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! I was missing the example.css file. I just needed to add the "input.editor-text" rule from the example css. Working perfect now. Thanks so much for this fantastic library! I hope to soon add to your list of example sites that use SlickGrid.